# $\int\limits_C e^{x^2-y^2}(\cos(2xy)dx+\sin(2xy)dy)$ over unit circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms, line-integrals, multiple-integral, greens-theorem

Let $C$ be the unit circle with positive orientation.

Find 
$$\int\limits_C e^{x^2-y^2}(\cos(2xy)dx+\sin(2xy)dy)$$

As I can see the differential form $e^{x^2-y^2}\cos(2xy)dx+e^{x^2-y^2}\sin(2xy)dy$ is not a closed form so it is also not exact. So, I tried to apply Green's theorem to get:
$$\iint\limits_B 4xe^{x^2 - y^2}\sin(2 x y) + 4ye^{x^2-y^2}\cos(2 x y)dxdy$$
With $B$ being the open unit disk. The thing is that a parametrization for the above will end up with expressions like $\sin(2r\cos\theta r\sin\theta)$ and things like that which I couldn't solve.

Is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Do not be frightened by its appearance. Notice that for each given $x$ the functions

   $$ y \mapsto 4x e^{x^2-y^2}\sin(2xy) \quad \text{and} \quad y \mapsto 4y e^{x^2-y^2}\cos(2xy) $$

   are odd. Since your domain of integration $B$ is symmetric about the $y$-reflection, it follows that the double integral is simply zero.
2. Alternatively, if you know a bit about complex analysis then the original line integral can be written as the following contour integral

   $$ \operatorname{Re}\left(\int_C \frac{e^{z^2}}{z^2} \, dz\right) $$

   Now by the residue theorem, this integral can be computed to be zero.

Comment: Very nice answer indeed. +1